# Use fluent nhibernate to retrieve parent object

Tags: nhibernate, fluent

I have a one to many mapping. When I try to retrieve the parent object the child object also comes up even if I stop lazy loading in mapping. I want to get only the parent object and not the child ones.How can I do?

Comment: From my experience, no matter what you tell NHibernate about lazy loading, if you access the child object while the session is active, it will lazy load the child object. If you access it while the session is inactive, it will fail with an exception...

Comment: so any other way out? at least if I can get null list of my child objects?

Comment: In NHinbernate theres a parameter called access, try setting access=none on the "one side" of the one-to-many relationship and remove the child property from the class.

Comment: You can permanently disable one side of the reference (by not mapping the parent to child make it one-way, or using something like what Filip suggested). In my case I sometimes do want to access the children and sometimes don't, and use eager loading when I do. I had to waste many, many hours to achieve this. I ended up wrapping NHibernate objects with a custom proxy that returns null when you try to access properties that were not fetched in the original query (the proxy prevents lazy loading and returns null instead). Perhaps I'll post the source some day, but it's a bit of a mess right now.

Comment: i tried what filip suggested but it still doesn't work out in my case.

Comment: When you say "it comes up" how do you know that it comes up? are you a) looking at just the generated SQL or b) using debug and seeing what is there?

Comment: @Rippo using debugger child objects are also getting retrieved.

Comment: When the debugger accesses the collectionproperty, then lazyloading triggers. if you dont use debugger and test if the collection is initialized (see my answer) then you would see _not loaded_. it would help if you add your use case to the question

Comment: @sovik so lazy loading is triggered when you look at the collection whilst debugging! thats your answer

Answer (score 1):

You are apparently triggering the lazy loading when you debug through your code.

If you are not sure what this means then please try to understand this:-

1. You put a breakpoint on your code
2. You retrieve the parent
3. Visual studio hits the breakpoint
4. You look to see if the children has been loaded
5. The visual studio debugger goes and retrieves the children for you <- This is what is causing your lazy loading. By observing this in VS you are forcing a lazy load.

If you are still not sure then please either add a SQL profiler, use logging via log4net or even download the [NHProf](http://nhprof.com/) (its free for 30 days) and see the generated sql with and then without the breakpoint and you will see the differences.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

why you access the childs if you dont need them? lazy collections aren't initialized when you dont access them. Maybe something like this in postloading event:

```
var pc = Parent.Childs as IPersistentCollection;
if (pc != null && !pc.WasInitialized)
    Parent.Childs = null;
```

Comment: i am actually using the retrieved parent object to save some other child elements using session.saveorupdate(Parent,child). If the previously saved child element also gets retrieved it's causing a problem .